How to authenticate via dotnet-cli to install a private package source on MacOS?
I am trying to build and run a .NET project in VSCode with extension c#Devkit on my MacOS.
As described the official microsoft documents I created nuget.config file to the root directory to get packages from our azure devops artifacts.
This is how my nuget.config looks like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Custom.Framework" value="https://pkgs.azure.com/example/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <Custom.Framework>
        <add key="Username" value="exampleUsername@example.com" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="my-clear-password" />
    </Custom.Framework>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>

Values here are just used to illustrate how nuget.config file appears but even if I am completely sure that my username and password are correct in my local machine I can't get success from the command below.
dotnet restore command
It outputs
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
I am not sure how should I build and run this project on my MacOS.

I had created a personal access token before I switched to VSCode. For Azure Devops I opened up the Personal Access Token menu and see my PATs. Delete them and create an another one. Changed the value for "ClearTextPassword" with the password generated by PAT that I just created.
Then it worked for me!
